# Help Me Identify My Old Norco Bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, road

I bought this bicycle second hand two years ago. The previous owner did not mention the model or year.

I messaged a Norco customer service representative. He couldn't pinpoint the model or year, but said it was probably from the early 90s.

The serial number of the frame is: Y9N3724

The wheels are not original.

Here is a link to an imgur album of more pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiZ9A.jpg

[image: profile picture of the bike]

Comment: That 'stem' is an abomination

Comment: Other than curiosity, I can't think of any situation in which you need a more precise date than "it's from the early '90s."

Answer (score 2):

Not easy with such an old bike, but i've managed to piece together some useful info.

I believe it is a Norco Monterey:
https://freelanderbicycles.com/blogs/news/17350229-the-restoration-of-brians-norco-monterey

https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1061887-early-1980s-norco-id-help.html

Further reading suggests that it was likely designed in Canada, but produced by Yamaguchi Sports in Japan.
With that in mind we can use the info in the following link to make a good guess at interpreting the serial number.

https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1042901-asian-serial-number-guide.html

So I think your bike was most likely manufactured during weeks 28-29 of 1979